# $m$ doesn't come in the sequence $a_n=[n+\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}]$ iff m is a perfect square

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive integers defined by

$a_n=[n+\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}]$

Show that a natural number $m$ doesn't occur in the sequence iff it is a square.

Comment: Hint: Check $a_{m^2-m}$ and $a_{m^2-m+1}$. Note that the sequence is increasing.

Comment: yes it is obvious. But then I am stucked up.

Comment: So for example you know that $a_{100}=110$. And you know that there were no repetitions among $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_{100}$. And you know that you missed out on $1,4,9,16,\ldots,100$. No room to miss any non-squares.

Comment: so one statement is true but since it is written iff, what about other?

Comment: Did you check $a_{m^2-m}$ and $a_{m^2-m+1}$?

Comment: Satvik: Adding on to Jyrki's comment, notice that $m^2 - m + 0.25 = (m - 0.5)^2$.

Comment: Great, Satvik! ${}$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The observations that you should make are

1. The square root is an increasing function. Thus for $f(n)=n+\sqrt n+\frac12$ we have $$f(n+1)>f(n)+1.$$ Consequently $a_{n+1}>a_n$ for all $n$.
2. We have $(m-\frac12)^2=m^2-m+\frac14$. Therefore $m-1<\sqrt{m^2-m}<m-\frac12$ and thus $$a_{m^2-m}=\left[(m^2-m)+\sqrt{m^2-m}+\frac12\right]=m^2-1.$$
3. Similarly $m>\sqrt{m^2-m+1}>m-\frac12$, so $$a_{m^2-m+1}=\cdots m^2+1.$$
4. Therefore $a_n\neq m^2$ for all $n,m$.
5. We have $a_{m^2}=m^2+m$, so in view of item 1 exactly $m$ of the integers in the range $[1,m^2+m]$ are missing from the sequence. In view of item 4 we know what those are. Here $m$ is arbitrary so we are done.

Answer (score 3):

If we label the *non-squares* in increasing order, then the number $m\colon= a^2 +d$, ($1\le d \le 2a)$ will have the label $n\colon = a^2+d-a$.  ( $-a$ since $a$ lesser squares are not counted in). Now we have to show that

$$m = n + \lfloor \sqrt{n}+ \frac{1}{2}\rfloor$$

or

$$a^2 + d = (a^2  - a+ d) + \lfloor\sqrt{a^2 -a + d} + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor$$

or

$$a = \lfloor\sqrt{a^2 -a + d} + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor$$

or
$$a-\frac{1}{2} \le \sqrt{a^2 -a + d} < a + \frac{1}{2}$$

which is not hard to check ( recall $1\le d \le 2a$).

Note: we get the *same* bijection from $\{1,2,\ldots\}$ to the non-squares by using the formula
$$n \mapsto n + \lfloor \sqrt{n + \delta_n} + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor$$

if $(\delta_n)_n$ is [any](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BIntegerPart%5Bn+%2B+Sqrt%5Bn%2B+Sin%5Bn%5D%2F5%5D%2B1%2F2%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D) sequence satisfying $-\frac{3}{4} \le \delta_n < \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks!